# Multipy after joining data in PIG

Tags: join, apache-pig

I am trying to multiply two fields and take their sum after joining three tables in Pig. However I keep on getting this error:

`<file loyalty_program.pig, line 30, column 74> (Name: Multiply Type: null Uid: null)incompatible types in Multiply Operator left hand side:bag :tuple(new_details1::new_details::potential_customers::num_of_orders:long)  right hand side:bag :tuple(products::price:int)`

```
-- load the data sets
orders = LOAD '/dualcore/orders' AS (order_id:int,
             cust_id:int,
             order_dtm:chararray);

details = LOAD '/dualcore/order_details' AS (order_id:int,
             prod_id:int);

products = LOAD '/dualcore/products' AS (prod_id:int,
             brand:chararray,
             name:chararray,
             price:int,
             cost:int,
             shipping_wt:int);
recent = FILTER orders by order_dtm matches '2012-.*$';

customer = GROUP recent by cust_id;

cust_orders = FOREACH customer GENERATE group as cust_id, (int)COUNT(recent) as num_of_orders;

potential_customers = FILTER cust_orders by num_of_orders>=5;

new_details = join potential_customers by cust_id, recent by cust_id;
new_details1 = join new_details by order_id, details by order_id;
new_details2 = join new_details1 by prod_id, products by prod_id;
--DESCRIBE new_details2;

final_details = FOREACH new_details2 GENERATE potential_customers::cust_id, potential_customers::num_of_orders as num_of_orders,recent::order_id as order_id,recent::order_dtm,details::prod_id,products::brand,products::name,products::price as price,products::cost,products::shipping_wt;

grouped_data = GROUP final_details by cust_id;

member = FOREACH grouped_data GENERATE SUM(final_details.num_of_orders * final_details.price)  ; 
lim = limit member 10;
dump lim;
```

I even casted the result of count to int. It still keeps on throwing this error at me. I have no clue how to go about it.

Comment: Ok. Could you give me the requirement here.. Pls give some sample  inputs and expected output.. I would like know that a order_id can have multiple prod_id or not..

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I think at first, you want to multiply no.of purchases with the price of each product and then you need total SUM of that multiplied value..

Even though this is a strange requirement, but you can go with below approach..

All you need to do is calculate the multiplication in final_details Foreach statement itself and simply apply the SUM for that multiplied amount..

Based on your  load statements I created  the below input files

main_orders.txt

```
6666,100,2012-01-01
7777,101,2012-09-02
8888,100,2012-01-09
9999,101,2012-12-08
6666,101,2012-09-02
9999,100,2012-07-12
9999,100,2012-08-01
6666,100,2012-01-02
7777,100,2012-09-09
```

orders_details.txt

```
6666,6000
7777,7000
8888,8000
9999,9000
```

main_products.txt

```
6000,Nike,Shoes,3000,3000,1
7000,Adidas,Cap,1000,1000,1
8000,Rebook,Shoes,4000,4000,1
9000,Puma,Shoes,25000,2500,1
```

Below is the code

```
orders = LOAD '/user/cloudera/inputfiles/main_orders.txt'  USING PigStorage(',') AS (order_id:int,cust_id:int,order_dtm:chararray);

details = LOAD '/user/cloudera/inputfiles/orders_details.txt'  USING PigStorage(',') AS (order_id:int,prod_id:int);

products = LOAD '/user/cloudera/inputfiles/main_products.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(prod_id:int,brand:chararray,name:chararray,price:int,cost:int,shipping_wt:int);

recent = FILTER orders by order_dtm matches '2012-.*';

customer = GROUP recent by cust_id;

cust_orders = FOREACH customer GENERATE group as cust_id, (int)COUNT(recent) as num_of_orders;


potential_customers = FILTER cust_orders by num_of_orders>=5;

new_details = join potential_customers by cust_id, recent by cust_id;
new_details1 = join new_details by order_id, details by order_id;
new_details2 = join new_details1 by prod_id, products by prod_id;
DESCRIBE new_details2;

final_details = FOREACH new_details2 GENERATE potential_customers::cust_id, potential_customers::num_of_orders as num_of_orders,recent::order_id as order_id,recent::order_dtm,details::prod_id,products::brand,products::name,products::price as price,products::cost,products::shipping_wt, (potential_customers::num_of_orders * products::price ) as multiplied_price;// multiplication is achived in last variable
dump final_details;

 grouped_data = GROUP final_details by cust_id;

member = FOREACH grouped_data GENERATE SUM(final_details.multiplied_price)  ; 
lim = limit member 10;
dump lim;
```

Just for clarity I am dumping the output of final_details foreach statement as well.

```
(100,6,6666,2012-01-01,6000,Nike,Shoes,3000,3000,1,18000)
(100,6,6666,2012-01-02,6000,Nike,Shoes,3000,3000,1,18000)
(100,6,7777,2012-09-09,7000,Adidas,Cap,1000,1000,1,6000)
(100,6,8888,2012-01-09,8000,Rebook,Shoes,4000,4000,1,24000)
(100,6,9999,2012-07-12,9000,Puma,Shoes,25000,2500,1,150000)
(100,6,9999,2012-08-01,9000,Puma,Shoes,25000,2500,1,150000)
```

final output is below

```
(366000)
```

This code may help you, but Please clarify your requirement again